# using a variable when getting an experimental variable

Tags: c

I have a list of server ports in an ini file. to get these and load them into a list I use a for loop. How can i use a variable to get this to work.

```
ServerAmount = 8;
int z;
ServerPort[];
for ( z = 0; z < ServerAmount; z++ )
{
  if(getenv('SERVERPORT[z]') != NULL)
  {
      ServerPort[z] = getenv('SERVERPORT[z]');
  }
}
```

So simply how do i get z to be passed as the number. (ie. SERVERPORT[1])

PS. Sorry if this is noob question.

Comment: It's not a noob question, it's a badly expressed question. `ServerPort[];` doesn't make sense. Post some good code.

Comment: You are looking for concatenating strings(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concatenation). In C, there is several functions useful to do it into `string.h` header.

Comment: isn't ServerPort[]; how one defines an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `sprintf`, let me know if this works for you:

```
ServerAmount = 8;
int z;
ServerPort[];
for ( z = 0; z < ServerAmount; z++ )
{
  char tmp[20];
  sprintf(tmp, "SERVERPORT[%i]", z);
  if(getenv(tmp) != NULL)
  {
      ServerPort[z] = getenv(tmp);
  }
}
```

EDIT:
By the way, `ServerPort[]` is not valid. You probably wanted to write something like:

```
char *ServerPort[8];
```

Comment: `%i` stands for integer (`z`). For further explanation about format identifiers read http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~liberti/public/computing/prog/c/C/FUNCTIONS/format.html